# Asp.Net Deploy multiple projects under one solution in multiple servers

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, azure

I made a c# asp.net solution and it has multiple projects in them. It has 3 API projects and 2 web projects and the client wants it such that all these Web and API projects are on different servers so that if one of them goes down due to overload or an error, the others can still work. There are also projects for BLL and DAL similar to a repository structure, but they can be on the same server. Is there any way to do that on Azure or AWS using gateways or multi-tenants? Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Do you want to know how to deploy api’s in multiple servers from one solution? Or you are asking how to load balance?

Comment: Want to know how to deploy multiple projects (not only API, but also web) in multiple servers from one solution.

Comment: Do you use any CI/CD pipeline? Or just deploy from Visual Studio?

Comment: Just Visual studio for now. Not sure what the right way is here.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is - If you have different deployment targets (different servers) for different projects (API, WEB etc) then break the solution and create individual solution for your Web, and API projects and commit them into separate repositories. Since you have only 4-5 projects this approach will work better for you.And deploy using a CI/CD pipeline.

Deploying directly from the visual studio to production server is never considered a good approach in the DevOps era.

However, if you do not want to break the repository and still want to use visual studio for deployment (or doesn't have Jenkins/Azure DevOps etc.) then. Right click on the project that you want to deploy. Click on Publish. Then you will have to select your target environment (IIS, Azure, Folder, FTP etc.) as the image below and publish the projects to server one by one.
[image]

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks so much

Comment: In the second method you recommended, can I deploy each project on different servers? How will the BLL/DLL talk to the WebApp and API if they are on different servers?

Comment: Yes. What is the project type of your BLL and DLL? Class library or something else? If they are class library then you should have taken them as project reference (or dll or nuget reference already) to the API & Web Projects. 
When you build the Web App and Api App then your BLL and DLL will be published along with.